# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $f:R \to R$ be a ring homomorphism.
If $S = \{a \in R | f(a)=a \}$, show that $S$ is subring of $R$.

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $f:R \to R$ be a ring homomorphism.
If $S = \{a \in R | f(a)=a \}$, show that $S$ is subring of $R$.

My attempt:

Let $m,n \in S$. That's, $f(m)=m$ and $f(n)=n$. Let $a\in S$. Now,
\begin{align*}
0_R = f(-a+a) &= f(-a) + f(a) \\
0_R &= f(-a) + a \\
f(-a) &= -a
\end{align*}
Thus, $-a \in S$.
Next, note that $f(m-n) = f(m) - f(n) = m - n \in S$ and $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)=mn \in S$.
Hence, by the subring test above, we obtain that $S$ is subring of $R$.

Is that correct? Hope an advice or correction for my attempt above. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You could make it shorter by using $f(-a)=-f(a)=-a$ to show that $-a\in S$, but that's just eye candy.

Comment: Thanks Sir ${}{}$

Comment: Also, depending on how "subring" is defined, you should check that $1 \in S$  as well.

Comment: @Doctor Who Since $0_R,1_R \in R$, then $1_R = f(0+1) = f(0) + f(1) = f(1)$. Thus, $1 \in S$. Like this?

Comment: @user795084 I don't understand how you got that $1_R = f(0 + 1)$. But generally, when one is dealing with commutative rings with unit, one defines a ring homomorphism to be a map with preserves addition, multiplication, and 1. So $1 = f(1)$ follows from the definition of a ring homomorphism.

Comment: okay sir ${}{}{}$